# Developing in Medium Trust with IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-express, medium-trust

I'm trying to setup an ASP.NET MVC 3 project to run in medium trust in visual studio with IIS Express because I have to deploy the app to GoDaddy :(

So in `<system.web>` I added `<trust level="Medium" />` but when running the project, I see this YSOD:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding this in the `machine.config` or the `web.config` that is in the framework directory.

Comment: Did you check to see if there is an existing element already defined?

Comment: Have you tried doing a "Clean All" first?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my fault. I had added the `<trust>` element to a web.config that was not the root web.config.

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at this thread http://forums.iis.net/t/1148147.aspx